# ¿Como activar evento al llegar a cierto punto de la pagina con javascript o jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Verán, tengo un menú en un sitio one page, en que al dar clic a un elemento del menú te baja a la sección indicada y el elemento seleccionado del menú queda subrayado, pero necesito que al hacer `scroll` y estar en esa sección también se subraye el elemento, podrían ayudarme?

Este es el sitio

[pagina de ejemplo](http://niccolo.liderlogo.info/)

Comment: Hermosa pagina es creación tuya o plantilla?

Comment: esta hecha con divi

Answer (score 2, accepted):

También puedes crear una especie de waypoints; es decir, cuando llege a cierto elemento, disparar un handler previamente asociado. Puedes crear tu propio código para esto o usar una librería como [Waypoints](http://imakewebthings.com/waypoints/).

```js
const waypoints = [
  {
    id: 'about',
    handler(direction) { console.log('About'); }
  },
  {
    id: 'contact',
    handler(direction) { console.log('Contact'); }
  }
];


waypoints.forEach(({ id, handler }) => (
  new Waypoint({
    element: document.getElementById(id),
    handler,
    offset: 20 // añade un margen superior opcional
  })
));
```

```css
.spacer {
  height: 200px;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/waypoints/4.0.1/noframework.waypoints.min.js"></script>

<a href="#home">Home</a>
<a href="#about">About</a>
<a href="#contact">Contact</a>

<h2 id="home">Home</h2>
<div class="spacer"></div>
<h2 id="about">About</h2>
<div class="spacer"></div>
<h2 id="contact">Contact</h2>
<div class="spacer"></div>
<div class="spacer"></div>
```

Comment: Uncaught Error: No element option passed to Waypoint constructor me aparece este error :(  @Gustavo García

Comment: @MichelNivellino debes ejecutar el código cuando el DOM esté listo: `document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() { // código aquí });`.

Comment: Me sigue apareciendo el mismo error @Gustavo

Comment: Si sigue saliendo ese error es que no estás pasando ningún elemento en el constructor de `Waypoint`, por lo que lo que obtienes con `document.getElementById` es `undefined`. Verifica los ids.

Comment: Disculpa, lo que pasaba es que estaba colocando en minusculas el id en el json, y en la pagina estaban en mayusculas, acabo de corregir, muchas gracias!

Comment: De nada, me alegro te haya servido. Va +1 para ti también.

Answer (score 1):

Puedes utilizar un offset, algo como:

```js
$(document).ready(function (){

var altura = $("#inicio").offset().top;
var altura2 = $("#section2").offset().top;

$(window).scroll(function(){

   if($(window).scrollTop() >= altura + 400) {

  $(".boton1").css({"font-weight": "600"});

}else{

  $(".boton1").css({"font-weight": "400"});

}

   if($(window).scrollTop() >= altura2) {

  $(".boton2").css({"font-weight": "600"});
  $(".boton1").css({"font-weight": "400"});

}else{

  $(".boton2").css({"font-weight": "400"});

}

   });
   
   $(".boton1").click(function(){

$("html, body").animate({scrollTop: altura},500);

  });
   
   $(".boton2").click(function(){

$("html, body").animate({scrollTop: altura2},500);

  });
 
});
```

```css
* {
 padding: 0;
 margin: 0;
 font-family: sans-serif;
}

html, body {
 width: 100%;
 height: 700px;
}

.section {
  height: 700px;
  width: 100%;
}

nav {
 position: fixed;
 width: 100%;
 height: 50px;
 text-align: center;
}

nav ul {
  list-style: none;
}

nav ul li {
  display: inline-block;
}

nav ul li a {
  display: block;
  padding: 16px 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: rgb(170, 92, 122);
}

nav ul li a:hover {
  font-weight: 600;
  color: rgb(148, 61, 95);
}

#section2 {
  background-color: lightgreen;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<nav>
  <ul>
    <li><a class="boton1" href="#inicio">Botón uno</a></li>
    <li><a class="boton2" href="#section2">Botón dos</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
<section class="section" id="inicio">

</section>
<section class="section" id="section2">

</section>
```

Explicación breve: cuando el documento está listo --> ( `$(document).ready();` ) aplico una variable con la función offset --> ( `var altura = $(".section").offset().top` ) para determinar la altura en `top` de la etiqueta o clase en cuanto a la ventana, y luego dentro de la función `ready()` aplico una función `scroll()` en la ventana `$(window)` y adentro agrego mis `if` de manera que si la ventana tiene un scroll en la altura top y es mayor o igual que la  variable anterior --> ( `if($(window).scrollTop() >= altura){ aqui las funciones}` ) aplico las funciones necesarias para animar, cambiar, etc. las etiquetas HTML que desee, en este caso, cambié los valores CSS de las etiquetas. Si quieres saber mas del tema o no comprendes bien, te recomiendo profundizar en el JQuery y estudiar las funciones `offset()` y `scroll()`.

Como dato adicional, puedes agregar tantas variables con la función `offset()`como secciones y botones del menu tengas, para que dentro de la función `scroll()` puedas agregar mas `if/else`. También afuera del la función `scroll()` agregué otras funciones para que al hacer click en los botones del menú, se desplace con una animación y no simplemente aparezca de golpe en la sección.

Comment: No entiendo muy bien el ejemplo amigo :(

Comment: Actualicé el ejemplo, fíjate bien en como está relacionado el JQuery al CSS y al HTML @m

Comment: Podrías publicar tu HTML CSS y JQuery para hacerte una explicación detallada con tu trabajo.

Answer (score 1):

El ejemplo que pones en concreto es una página WordPress en la que se utiliza el [plugin jQuery Smooth Scroll](https://es.wordpress.org/plugins/jquery-smooth-scroll/)

Para hacerlo tú mismo deberías controlar el evento `scroll` del elemento contenedor sobre el que se va a hacer el scroll:

```
 // Únicamente javascript (sin librerías)
 scrollableElement.addEventListener('scroll', scrollHandler);

 // o utilizando jQuery
 $(scrollableElement).scroll(scrollHandler);
```

En la función `scrollHandler` puedes obtener la posición de cada elemento y, si ha llegado a la posición superior, activas la opción de menú.

Aquí tienes un ejemplo con jQuery:

```js
$(function(){
  // div con el contenido
  var $content = $('#content');
  // barra de navegación
  var $nav = $('#nav');
  
  // secciones
  var secciones = [
    { menu: $('#intro'), content: $('#secIntro') },
    { menu: $('#ap1'), content: $('#secAp1') },
    { menu: $('#ap2'), content: $('#secAp2') },
    { menu: $('#ap3'), content: $('#secAp3') },
    { menu: $('#ap4'), content: $('#secAp4') }
  ];
  
  
  // Al hacer scroll
  $content.scroll(function(){
    // Quitamos la clase de todas las opciones de menu
    $nav.find('a').removeClass('active');
    // Recorremos las secciones de abajo a arriba
    // Activamos la primera cuya posición sea 40 o menor (ha llegado a la parte superior)
    // Le damos un margen de 40 para que no sea necesario que llegue hasta el borde
    for (var i=secciones.length -1; i >= 0; i--){
      // Posición superior de la sección
      var top = secciones[i].content.offset().top;
      // Si ha llegado arriba activamos el menú y salimos
      if (top <= 40){
        secciones[i].menu.addClass('active');
        return;
      }
    }
    // Si no ha llegado ninguna arriba activamos la intro
    $('#intro').addClass('active');
  });
});
```

```css
html, body{
  height: 95%;
  margin: 0;
}
#nav{
  padding: 5px;
}
#nav a{
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #666666;
}
#nav a:hover {
  color: #000000;
}
#nav a.active{
  color: #cc3333;
}
#content{
  overflow-y: scroll;
  height: 95%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="nav">
  <a id="intro" class="menu active" href="#secIntro">Introducción</a>
  <a id="ap1" class="menu" href="#secAp1">Apartado 1</a>
  <a id="ap2" class="menu" href="#secAp2">Apartado 2</a>
  <a id="ap3" class="menu" href="#secAp3">Apartado 3</a>
  <a id="ap4" class="menu" href="#secAp4">Apartado 4</a>
</div>
<div id="content">
  <div id="secIntro">
    <h3>Introducción</h3>
    <p>....</p>
    <p>....</p>
    <p>....</p>
    <p>....</p>
  </div>
  <div id="secAp1">
    <h3>Apartado 1</h3>
    <p>....</p>
    <p>....</p>
    <p>....</p>
    <p>....</p>
  </div>
  <div id="secAp2">
    <h3>Apartado 2</h3>
    <p>....</p>
    <p>....</p>
    <p>....</p>
    <p>....</p>
  </div>
  <div id="secAp3">
    <h3>Apartado 3</h3>
    <p>....</p>
    <p>....</p>
    <p>....</p>
    <p>....</p>
  </div>
  <div id="secAp4">
    <h3>Apartado 4</h3>
    <p>....</p>
    <p>....</p>
    <p>....</p>
    <p>....</p>
    <p>....</p>
    <p>....</p>
    <p>....</p>
    <p>....</p>
    <p>....</p>
    <p>....</p>
    <p>....</p>
    <p>....</p>
    <p>....</p>
    <p>....</p>
    <p>....</p>
    <p>....</p>
  </div>
</div>
```